# Reference to Basemap instance's coordinate system

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib, coordinate-transformation, matplotlib-basemap

I use the matplotlib basemap toolkit (`mpl_basemap.Basemap`) to plot GeoTIFF images on a map background using `pcolor()` or `pcolormesh()`. For this purpose, I need to transform a meshgrid of x and y coordinates of the raster data into the coordinate system of the plot, for example polar stereographic. Currently, this is how I accomplish this:

- Create an `osr.SpatialReference()` object and use it to grab the coordinates of the GeoTiff image via its `ImportFromWkt()` method, called with the GeoTIFF's projection as an argument.
- Export this spatial reference to proj4 via `.ExportToProj4()` and use it to create a `pyproj.Proj()` object.
- Call this class instance with `inverse=True` on a meshgrid of easting and northing values of the GeoTIFF image to create a lat/long meshgrid
- Call the Basemap class instance on this lat/long meshgrid to create a meshgrid in the Basemap object's coordinate system

Is there an easier way that doesn't proceed through a lat/long representation? If I could get a reference to the coordinate system of the Basemap instance, I could set up a coordinate transform directly between the GeoTIFF dataset and the map.

Comment: Whoa. maybe also try http://gis.stackexchange.com